# Placement of Flatten layer in deep learning model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I make a deep learning model for classification. The model consist of 4 Conv2d layer, 1 pooling layer, 2 dense layer and 1 flatten layer. When i do this arrangement of layers: Conv2D, Conv2D, Conv2D, Conv2D, pooling, dense, flatten, dense then my results are good. But when i follow this arrangement: Conv2D, Conv2D, Conv2D, Conv2D, pooling, flatten, dense, dense then the classification results are not good. My question is putting flatten layer between two dense layer is correct or not?

Can I follow the pattern of layer by which i am getting good classification results?

Comment: Tips: as such type of question is not fit in SO, you can communicate with chat-gpt.

Comment: This question is borderline off-topic, as it is not really a problem about coding. If you could describe the insufficient behavior of the second case a bit closer, the question could fit, somewhat, the requirements for AI.stackexchange.com

Comment: No matter the shape (1D, 2D, 3D, ...) of your layer, using "Dense1 <-> Flatten <-> Dense2" or "Dense1 <-> Dense2" does not change anything because every cell of Dense1 will be connected to every cell of Dense2. However, using Flatten after Global(Average|Max) pooling change the result because you increase the number of connections to the Dense1 layer.  (now, I'm not really sure of what I said...)

Comment: You can also add a little more details about your model such as the number of filters, or you can give the `model.summary()`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, it is not recommended to sandwich a flatten layer between dense layers, and as suggested by Corralien, It doesn't provide any value. Your other architecture `Conv2D, Conv2D, Conv2D, Conv2D, pooling, flatten, dense, dense` is more legit. If your model is providing you with good results, you might want to keep it, but technically you do not need the flatten layer between the two dense layers.

You can consider using `Conv2D, Conv2D, Conv2D, Conv2D, Pooling, dense, dense`. Or a better alternative would be to try playing with your architecture. Such as adding another pooling layer between the four `Conv2d` layers like: `Conv2D, Conv2D, Pooling, Conv2D, Conv2D, Pooling, flatten, dense, dense`, and proceed with adjusting your hyperparameters.